# Cartan matrix of the full transformation monoid ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $T_n$ be the full transformation monoid of an $n$-set and $A_n=KT_n$ its monoid algebra over the complex numbers.

> Question 1: Is the Cartan matrix of $A_n$ known? Im especially interested to see it for $n=5$ and $n=6$.

The Coxeter matrix of an algebra is defined as $M=- C^{-1} C^T$ when $C$ is the Cartan matrix. It is called periodic if $M^n=id$ for some $n \geq 1$ (the minimal such $n$ is then called the period).

> Question 2: For which $n$ is the Coxeter matrix of $A_n$ periodic? What is the period?

I noted it is periodic for $n \leq 4$ and I do not know the Cartan matrix for higher $n$.
The period for $n=4$ is 11 for example.

Comment: So K is C I suppose.  But you could take Q since it is a splitting field

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Just took it for safety, but then the field does not matter as long as the characteristic is 0.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: There is a combinatorially defined matrix that is similar to the Coxeter matrix that may be easier for the computer to do for smaller  n.

Comment: My memory is that computing this cartan matrix is equivalent to hard questions about plethysms.  I think I have an old mo question about it and Putcha told me this back in 2002 but I don't remember if he writes about it in his paper

Comment: See my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198872/decomposing-mathbb-cn-otimes-m-as-a-representation-of-s-n-times-s-m

Comment: Finding the cartan matrix is the same as decomposing the tensor product of n copies of C^n as a T_n-bimodule into simples.  If you can do it for T_n you can do it for S_n by Putcha's computation of the character table. So this is as hard as an "impossible" problem about inner plethysms

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg But having quiver and relations of $KT_n$ would yield the Cartan matrix in seconds (as it has entries all paths from one vertex $i$ to another vertex $j$), so that makes it unlikely that all relations are known it seems. Any chance to get the matrix for $n=5$ and $n=6$ at least to check periodicity? Maybe there is some software for monoids out there that can do this.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg By the way, the Coxeter matrix can also be found in the Grothendieck group of a finite dimensional algebra with  finite global dimension(with basis the indeocmposble projectives) as the matrix of the map sending an indecomposable projective P to the negative of the indecomposable injective I=$\nu(P)$ (Nakayama functor applied to P). Thus finding the Coxeter matrix can be done by knowing explicitly the projective resolution of all indecomposable injective modules.

Comment: The minimal projective resolutions of the simples are now known in the languages of representations of the category of sets.  I am not sure about the injective envelopes.

Comment: I'm a bit confused since the indecomposable injective represents an element of $G_0$  not in $K_0$. Or do you mean take the inverse image of the injective indecomposable under the Cartan matrix?  I guess $-C^{-1}C^T$ should be that

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Im not sure what you mean. The definition of the Grothendieck group can be found for example on page 5 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04281.pdf . When $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra of finite global dimension basis of the Grothendieck group are given by simple modules or indecomposable projective modules or indecomposable injective modules. The Coxeter matrix expresses the indecomposable injectives (up to a minus sign) in terms of the indecomposables projective. To get this expression one has to know the projective resolutions of the injective indecomposable modules.

Comment: Ok.  I think of these as different groups that happen to be isomorphic in the finite global dimension case.  We are saying the same thing then

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg By the way, is $KT_n$ a Koszul algebra? It is true for $n \leq 4$. That might give some information on the Cartan matrix.

Comment: Since we don't know the relations I don't even know if it is quadratic.  I believe the quiver gets multiple edges for $n$ large enough but I can't recall.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to question 1 is no in general, although it may be known for small values.  The problem of computing the Cartan matrix of $\mathbb CT_n$ is at least as hard as some famous problems about computing inner plethysms for symmetric group representations as mentioned in my old MO question [Decomposing $(\mathbb C^n)^{\otimes m}$ as a representation of $S_n\times S_m$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198872/decomposing-mathbb-cn-otimes-m-as-a-representation-of-s-n-times-s-m).

Basically, the Cartan matrix is just a description of the composition factors of $\mathbb CT_n$ as a $\mathbb CT_n\otimes \mathbb CT_n^{op}$-module.  Now $\mathbb CT_n$ can be identified with $(\mathbb C^n)^{\otimes n}$ as a $CT_n$-bimodule.  If you knew how to find these, then because Putcha computed the restriction of each $\mathbb CT_n$ simple to $\mathbb CS_n$, you would be able to decompose $(\mathbb C^n)^{\otimes n}$ as a $\mathbb CS_n$-bimodule, which is a well known difficult problem in computing inner plethysms. In fact, if $e_r$ is an idempotent fixing the first $r$ elements and no others, then $\mathbb T_ne_r$ is an $\mathbb CT_n\otimes \mathbb CT_r$-bimodule isomorphic to $(\mathbb C^n)^{\otimes r}$ and its restriction to $S_n\times S_r$ would be computable if you knew the Cartan matrix of $\mathbb CT_n$, so you would also be able to decompose this bimodule into simples and so compute all inner plethysms (as per my question). This is why I asked that question years ago.